# Function call to declare object property in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to use function call to set an object property in js? I tried but it didn't work.

```js
var name = "Richard";

function showName() {
  var name = "Jack"; // local variable; only accessible in this showName function​
  console.log(name); // Jack​
}
console.log(name); // Richard: the global variable

var myObj = {
  name: showName();
};

console.log(myObj.name);
```

Comment: `showName` does not return anything so `myObj.name` is going to be `undefined`

Comment: The answer is "yes" but your function has to actually `return` something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to use function call to set an object property in js?

Yes, the right-hand side of a *property initializer* can contain any expression, including a function call. The expression is evaluated and the resulting value is assigned to the property. *(And if you have multiple property initializers in an object initializer, they're executed in source-code order.)*

Your example didn't work because you didn't return the `name` from `showName` (and because it has an extra `;`):

```js
var name = "Richard";

function showName() {
  var name = "Jack";
  snippet.log(name);
  return name;       // <== Added return name;
}
snippet.log(name);

var myObj = {
  name: showName()   // <== Removed ;
};

snippet.log(myObj.name);
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you. That makes sense.